# How to get viewcontroller in storyboard by identifier?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I try to get a viewcontroller from storyboard like this:

```
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    ViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"vc"];
    ViewController *avc = ((UINavigationController *)(_window.rootViewController)).topViewController;
```

But they are not the same object:

```
(lldb) po vc <ViewController: 0x17eaee50>
(lldb) po avc <ViewController: 0x17e72970>
```

Why?

Comment: `vc` is a new object while `avc` is an object already created that you retrieve.

Comment: When you say "try to get a view controller", do you mean, you're trying to get a pointer to one that's already instantiated, or are you trying to instantiate a new one?

Comment: Oh! I don't know **instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier** will create a new one...

Comment: Any way to get the already created viewcontroller from storyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are of the same class, but different instances. `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` instantiates a new view controller, as the name implies :).

Comment: I made a mistake...Any way to get the already created viewcontroller from storyboard?

Comment: No, not from the storyboard. How to get the controller depends on your controller and view structure.